# Can't send an OTP using request module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am working on a test project, where I have to send OTP in emails from https://www.xbiz.com/services/newsletters site. I am getting status code 200 but the OTP isn't sent to my mail.
Here is my code:

```
import requests as re
payload = {'email' : 'XYZ@YZX.com'}
x = re.post("https://www.xbiz.com/services/newsletters",data = payload)
print(x)
```

How to get the OTP in my mail without using selenium type stuffs ?

Comment: there's probably some sort of authentication sent either with the data or a header

Comment: is there any way to analyze it and make a script for sending otp? @ti7